# How to include a button in InfoWindow

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY) on how to add custom info window to a google map marker,
in the UIView I've added a button and created an IBAction but when I click on it nothing happen

my infoWindow view code looks like this

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Details.h"

@interface MarkerInfoWindowView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;

- (void) initializeWithDetails:(Details*)p_details;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MarkerInfoWindowView.h"

@implementation MarkerInfoWindowView

- (void) initializeWithDetails:(Details*)p_details
{
    if(self != nil)
    {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:p_basicDetails.imageURL];
        self.label1.text = p_details.l1;
        self.label2.text =  p_details.l2;
    }
}

-(IBAction) btn1_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
}
@end
```

and then in my view controller of the main screen and map

```
-(MarkerInfoWindowView*) customInfoWindow
{
    if(_customInfoWindow == nil)
    {
        _customInfoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MarkerInfoWindowView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return _customInfoWindow;
}

- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)p_mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)p_marker
{   
    Details* temp = [[Details alloc] init];
    temp.l1 = @"L1";
    temp.l2 = @"L2";
    temp.imageURL = @"someImage.jpg";

    [self.customInfoWindow initializeWithDetails:temp];

    return self.customInfoWindow;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What does _your_ code look like?

Comment: @geocodezip added the code (although is the same one from the tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the reason for the button not being clicked is because google-maps takes the UIView and renders it as an imageView so the button is part of an image and of course not clickable.

the solution is to add a UIView and handle on your own the hide/show and positioning.
instead of using

- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)p_mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)p_marker

i used didTapMarker and returned YES;

Comment: It is right. I had to override more methods including `mapView:markerInfoWindow:` I don't understand why info window is rendered as a image.