# Google Maps iOs SDK : Add an action to a custom InfoWindow

Tags: xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add an action on a button using the custom infowindow.
Looks like this infowindow is rendered as an image and can't take any action.

I'm using this method:

```
-(UIView *) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    //my code
}
```

I added my Custom infowindow within a .XIB file. I would like to trigger the event `touchupinside` but still can't achieve this.

Some links I tried to follow unsuccessfully:

- [on google code](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4961)
- [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091564/how-to-include-a-button-in-infowindow)

Thanks!

**EDIT**
For Apple Maps, it can be achieved using [this beautiful class available on github](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview).

Answer (score 0):

```
If you check GMSMapView.h within GoogleMaps.Framework, you can see the below method which should let you add a custom infowindow for a marker, instead of using standard title and snippet alone:

NOTE you (op) say annotationView=infoWindow
BUT NORMAL: annotationView = marker itself and calloutView = infoWindow
```

Visit [Custom annotation view in Google Maps SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267183/custom-annotation-view-in-google-maps-sdk)

Comment: I already added this function :) I will try the Smccallout plugin !